# Google Cloud Engine: PubSub instead of RabbitMQ

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-pubsub

My project has microserver architecture working in Google Cloud. I'm thinking about moving from container with RabbitMQ to PubSub engine.

The question is: is it possible to receive messages one by one? My code is written on Go and [docs](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/pubsub#hdr-Receiving) says

> The callback is invoked concurrently by multiple goroutines,
>   maximizing throughput.

But how many goroutines can be invoked? How can I set the max allowed? E.g. one of my workers works with third-party API allowing only one connection per IP, so I can have only one task in time for this worker.

Comment: This question is probably going to be closed as off-topic for SO. This site is about code-specific problems, not architectural/technology decisions. The core idea though is that you pull down 1 message from the topic, to which the callback is applied. That call looks somethiing like `go callback(msg)`. Meanwhile, another message _could_ be available, why wait for the callback to return? You could enforce this by adding a mutex to your callback, and just obtain a lock each time, but that's silly

Comment: Ye, that's the idea. But it's not architectural decision. The question is how PubSub really works, because it's unclear from docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct solution is App Engine Task Pull Queues

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/taskqueue/overview-pull